# How do I calculate column percentages for all columns in a data.table or dataframe in R?

Tags: r

Would like to calculate percentages for all columns in a concise way. In the resulting data.table or dataframe, each column should sum to 100%.

For example, I tried this code, but I didn't get the result I wanted.

```
salary <- c(5, 10, 35)
score <- c(10,15,25)
df<-data.frame(salary,score)
lapply(df,function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
```

The result was not what I wanted:

```
$salary
x  
       5         10        35 
0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 

$score
x
       10        15        25 
0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

The actual result I want is a dataframe or data.table as follows (with each number representing the percentage of the column total that the input dataframe or data.table had):

```
salary  score
.1      .2
.2      .3
.7      .5
```

I would like to be able to do this easily even for a data.table that has 100 columns.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible exmaple and expected output.

Comment: I made the required edits. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) x / sum(x)))
```

Gives us:

```
  salary score
1    0.1   0.2
2    0.2   0.3
3    0.7   0.5
```

The anonymous function transforms a vector of raw values (`x`) into a vector of proportions. `lapply` applies this function to every column of `df`, returning a list. Finally, `as.data.frame` converts the list back to a data frame.

Alternately, this can be done with the `prop.table` function you were trying to use originally. The only complication is that `prop.table` expects an array and not a data frame, so you have to convert from one to the other, and then back again:

```
as.data.frame(prop.table(as.matrix(df), 2))
```

Also gives us:

```
  salary score
1    0.1   0.2
2    0.2   0.3
3    0.7   0.5
```

Comment: Because the OP specifically said he wanted the output in a data frame or data table, not a matrix. Other than that, I don't disagree with your comment. :)

Comment: See the `setDF` or `setDT` functions, both of which can convert a `list` to a `data.frame`/`data.table` _by reference_, no copy needed ;-)

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know that!

Comment: NP. Sorry to come off as rude. I didn't realize your output was a `list` at first.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jdobres I figured out a solution using just data.table.

```
salary <- c(5, 10, 35)
score <- c(10,15,25)
dt<-data.table(salary,score)
output<-dt[,lapply(.SD, function (x) x/sum(x))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#d=ncol(df)
#df$per <- with(df, df$col/d*100)
```

Comment: i am usinng this for finding percentages for cloumns. try this

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was asking. I edited the question to make my request clearer, sorry for not doing that earlier.